# Constructing a Cube with a dual norm

Tags: normed-spaces

Let $X = \mathbb{R}^m $ and ||.|| be a norm on $X$. The dual norm is defined as $||y||_*:=\sup\{ \langle\,x,y\rangle :||x|| \leq 1\}$

a) Show that $||.||_*$ is also a norm.
b) Construct two norms $||.||^O$ and $||.||^C$ so that:
$\{x:||x||^O=1\}$ is a regular octahedron
and $\{x:||x||^C=1\}$ is a cube.

I have a problem with b).

I'm far away from being an expert with norms. Just starting yet.
Now I've read that the 1-norm defines an octahedron and the dual norm of it, is a cube, so $\{x:||x||^O:=||x||_1 = |x|+|y|+|z| = 1\}$.

So from the definition we get the cube $||x||_*=\sup\{\langle\,x,y\rangle :||x||_1 \leq 1\},$
but now I'm not sure how this inner product is defined, since we have 3 entries $x$,$y$, and $z$. Would this work?

Comment: Hopefully you've also read that the dual norm of the $1$-norm is the $\infty$-norm, and it has a *much* nicer definition than as the dual of the $1$-norm!

Comment: Also, be careful of using $x$ and $y$ as vectors, as well as $x$, $y$, and $z$ are coordinates of $x$. It makes the definition of the octahedron quite confusing.

Comment: How would you write it? $|x_1| + |x_2| + |x_3| $ ?

Comment: Yeah, like that, or instead of the vector $x$, you could write $(x, y, z)$.